# 'IApplicationBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'UseWebAssemblyDebugging'

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-client-side, blazor-webassembly

I am creating a new Client-side Blazor PWA and received the following error messages after installing a few NUGET packages:

[image]

It looks like this is a known issue, but am confused why it has not been fixed yet as it was reported several months ago: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-46561

Is their a workaround I can do in the meantime?

Here are the NUGET packages/versions that I installed if that makes a difference:
[image]

Comment: You linked to the JetBrains Rider bug tracker, but I could swear your screenshots are from Visual Studio.

Comment: That is not my article.  That is just an article I found on Google and noticed it was from June.  Surprised Microsoft hasn't fixed this yet.

Comment: What you linked to it a bug report for the JetBrains Rider IDE, a product not developed by Microsoft. Is there some explicit indication in the report that it is a Microsoft issue? If not, then I would assume that the relationship between that report and your issue is completely coincidental, and suggest you look elsewhere for a resolution. (For instance, if the errors are coming from code you wrote that uses this WASM library, then you could share a minimal reproducible portion of that code.)

Comment: Ok I understand. To clarify, this is a brand new Blazor PWA project and the only changes I have made are 1) added a conn string 2) added NUGET packages to the dependencies. I haven't actually written much of anything, which is why I was confused and then stumbled upon that article. And yes, I am using visual studio.

Comment: Based on the version string, I'd guess that your project needs to be .NET Core 5 or it won't work. Is it? Otherwise, I don't personally have any tips, other than rebuilding the solution and restarting VS.

Comment: I can add "try to delete the `bin` and `obj` folders of all projects manually"

Comment: target the 3.2 package to get those methods. apparently, they are obsolete in the 5.0 packages.

Answer (score 6):

You need to install the package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Server

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hello @Rufaida, I do not have that dependency in my WASM and, yet, it works. So, I agree with the previous comment. You really need to explain why and in what situations that package is the solution.

Comment: @Jan, you probably use the blazor sdk, that's why. The answer is actually correct, but not very explanatory... :)

Answer (score 5):

The `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Server` package main version number (like 7.x.x -> 7) should match the target framework version number.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and what works for me was to change the target framework to.NET 6